# Realpath output includes the input

Tags: bash

I use the `realpath` command, but it always adds the original input at the end of the path:

```
$ pwd
/homes/yosefkl
$ realpath yosefkl
/homes/yosefkl/yosefkl
```

Comment: You're asking for a directory inside your current working directory. Try this instead: `realpath .`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You gave `realpath` a relative path, to a file in the current directory.

The file (which may be a directory) may or may not exist. `realpath` does not care by default. It reports the path regardless of whether its last element exists.

If you want it to only report paths that exist, use the `-e` flag:

```
zanna@toaster:~/playground$ realpath playground
/home/zanna/playground/playground
zanna@toaster:~/playground$ realpath ~/playground
/home/zanna/playground
zanna@toaster:~/playground$ realpath -e playground
realpath: playground: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12):

That's because you're giving it a path that doesn't exist, so it simply prints out the current directory and whatever you gave it, assuming that would be the path. Note that the man page specifies that:

> Print the resolved absolute file name; **all but the last component must exist**

So it allows execution with a nonexistent target. To illustrate, consider these examples:

```
$ pwd
/home
$ ls
lost+found  terdon
$ realpath terdon
/home/terdon
$ realpath nonExistentDir
/home/nonExistentDir
```

Or, to duplicate what you did:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon
$ realpath terdon
/home/terdon/terdon
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it only tells you that the path to the (probably non-existent) file `yosefkl` located in the current directory (`/homes/yosefkl`) is `/homes/yosefkl/yosefkl`. Try

```
realpath "$PWD"
```